Conditional distribution of union of data
Suppose we have multiple disjoint datasets, each characterized by a joint probability distribution. Let each dataset ( D_k ) consist of pairs $(x_i^{(k)}, y_i^{(k)})$ where $ x_i^{(k)} \in \mathbb{R}^d $ and $ y_i^{(k)} \in \mathbb{R}^s $. The joint probability distribution of each dataset is denoted as $P_{X^{(k)}, Y^{(k)}} $. The conditional probability distribution $P_{X^{(k)} \mid Y^{(k)}} $ is the same across all datasets.
The global joint distribution $P_{X,Y} $ is the distribution of the union of the disjoint datasets $ D_k $.
Given that the conditional distributions $ P_{X^{(k)} \mid Y^{(k)}} $ are the same for all datasets, does this imply that the global conditional distribution $ P_{X \mid Y} $ is also the same as the local conditional distributions $ P_{X^{(k)} \mid Y^{(k)}} $? Intuitively, this makes sense, but how can I show it?

Hi: The joint distribution can always be written as a function of the conditional so, if your conditionals are the same across all of the individual data sets, then the joint should be the same across all datasets also.

You argue with the joint, but does this also hold for the conditionals?

@markleeds: But the marginals can differ, so this cannot be true.

The wording of the question might be somewhat improved. I assume your $P_{X^{(k)}\mid Y^{(k)}}$ refers to one pair of $(x_i^{(k)}, y_i^{(k)})$ only. Otherwise the dimensions of these random vectors won't match.
Also, I assume that, by "disjoint", you imply "independent". Further, some conditional independence within each data set is also needed: $X_i^{(k)} \perp X_j^{(k)} \mid Y_i^{(k)}, Y_j^{(k)}$ for $i\neq j$.

Hi Sarah: If there is only one global joint distribution, then I would think that there would be one global conditional distribution. But maybe I'm not understanding because if there is only one overall joint distribution, then the marginals should be global also ?But you're saying that the marginals are different for each dataset ?

@ZackFisher. Yes the conditionals refer to one pair.  Why would I need this conditional independence?

So in this setup I could assume that the global condional is a convex combination of the local ones. Since they are the same, this should give the result?

@markleeds. Yes there should be only one global conditional. The marginal  regarding $y^k$ can vary since the number of data pairs for each dataset can be different.

Conditional independence seems needed to factor out the marginals of $Y$ component.

How would you argue then?

Sarah: Thanks for explanation but I'm gonna stay out of this one. ( too many personal things going on at the moment ). Hopefully Zack can help you out. Good luck.

Consider only the following setting.
If for joint distributions we have
$$
\begin{gathered}
P_{X,Y}=\lambda_1P_{X,Y}^{(1)}+\dots+\lambda_KP_{X,Y}^{(K)},\\
0\leqslant\lambda_i\leqslant1, \, \lambda_1+\dots+\lambda_K=1,
\end{gathered}
$$
then for marginal distributions it also holds that
$$
P_Y=\lambda_1P_Y^{(1)}+\dots+\lambda_KP_Y^{(K)}.
$$
With the fact that $P_{X|Y}^{(k)}\equiv \widetilde P_{X|Y}$ for all $k$, we obtain
$$
\begin{aligned}
P_{Y}P_{X|Y}&=\lambda_1P_Y^{(1)}\widetilde P_{X|Y}+\dots+\lambda_KP_Y^{(K)}\widetilde P_{X|Y},\\
P_{X|Y}&=\widetilde P_{X|Y},\quad \text{a.e.}[P_Y].
\end{aligned}
$$

Thank you very much for the answer. Is there a way to argue that if $$
P_Y=\lambda_1P_Y^{(1)}+\dots+\lambda_KP_Y^{(K)}.
$$ holds and we have that  $P_{X|Y}^{(k)}\equiv \widetilde P_{X|Y}$ , then we also have that $$
\begin{gathered}
P_{X,Y}=\lambda_1P_{X,Y}^{(1)}+\dots+\lambda_KP_{X,Y}^{(K)},\
0\leqslant\lambda_i\leqslant1, , \lambda_1+\dots+\lambda_K=1,
\end{gathered}
$$

The first equality defines a distribution $P_Y$ but the second one doesn't involve $P_X$ or $P_{X|Y}$, so you can't get information of $P_{X,Y}$.
